# Different layout before and after refreshing

Tags: css, html, browser-refresh

I am working on this [website](http://9amresourceagency.com/index.php). I used firebug along with DreamWeaver to create it. The website does not load fine when the page is opened(the layout is not as I wanted and I created it.) but when I refresh the page, it becomes exactly as I wanted it to be. Now I am stuck with it. I have never been into such a situation before. Please help me out how can I make the website load properly at the first instant. Thanks

Comment: To me it looks exactly the same before and after refresh (Chrome 19/Win7).

Comment: It looks the same. Btw. you may try to reduce the size of `rotate.gif`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the connection was slow the first time you loaded it. So the layout took longer. Next time you loaded it, everything was in the cache and the layout was quick!

So your low bandwidth (HTML) version of the site loads a 7.46 MB animated gif? Wow... I would get rid of that animated gif! Makes your site look choppy and unprofessional! That is surely a big part of your problem.

Comment: Actually, I was not the only person who said that it looked different at the first instant. I was working remotely with someone and he emailed me that the site does not load properly at the first instance. It must be the cache issue. Thanks everyone.

Comment: To me it's slightly different every time I reload the page, because it's trying to display that animated gif

Answer (score 2):

It looks exactly the same to me both before and after refresh. Hard-reset your cache, make sure you're not on a destructive proxy, and try using your browser in private mode.

Comment: Thanks. Off topic: would love to connect with you and get updates. Added you on twitter.